# Visual Studio 2010 Resources (WPF)

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, resources, manifest, embedded-resource

I was in visual studio and had a class file: **Foo.cs** ... I created a a resource (resx) file called **Foo.resx** because I also plan on having a **Foo.es-SP.resx**.

Visual studio, very nicely, tucked away the resource file the same way it tucks away code-behind files for xaml pages.

The problem is the application won't compile because the resource generator created a Foo.Designer.cs (designer) class that has an internal Foo class for the resource, which is the same class name as my Foo class:

**Foo.cs**

```
public class Foo { ... }
```

**Foo.Designer.cs**

```
internal class Foo { ... }
```

which is quite annoying because my application will not compile now. So, I figured I'd trick Visual Studio here and rename the file (not the class itself). I now have FooC.cs and FooC.resx and FooC.Designer.cs. This changed the resx class to `internal class FooC { ... }`

It compiles, but doesn't crashes when I run the application when I try to grab a resource.

1. Why does Visual Studio create an internal class that collides with my existing class? It's obvious that creating a resource for you class should have the same name because it organizes it for you.
2. Why is it that I get a runtime error when I try to use the resource that is marked as "Embedded Resource"?

Error Message:

> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException:
>   Could not find any resources
>   appropriate for the specified culture
>   or the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "MyProj.FooC.resources" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly
>   "MyProj" at compile time, or that all
>   the satellite assemblies required are
>   loadable and fully signed.    at
>   System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String
>   fileName)

Answer (score 0):

Select Foo.es-SP.resx in the solution explorer, display its properties (F4), and clear the Custom Tool property

Comment: I haven't even gotten to Foo.es-SP.resx yet. I'm still trying to get Foo.resx to work properly...

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do you plan on using the generated class? If not, clear the custom tool for Foo.resx, and it won't generate a class

Comment: I want to be able to use the String resources I type into the resource file. I have "Title" as one of my resource strings, but how do I actually use it in my class if I keep on getting these errors. Ideally I'd love to have my resource be only internal to my assembly, but also not give me these collisions with naming and if I don't name the resource file the same as the class file VS does not organize it nicely. I could add a FooResources.resx and reference it in, but Foo.resx is much nicer.

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of you Foo.resx to, e.g., FooResources.resx.

Comment: Yes, that resolved the issue of having two Foo classes, but then I'm still having the other issue. Also, this makes the resource just sit there instead of being organized by Visual Studio.

Comment: From my own experience i wouldn't advise you to deviate a lot from the pattern that microsoft designed - you'll later end up try to fight (and maybe win) against the pattern.
I usually create resource files in a different folder within the project. That, by default, puts them in a different namespace therefore i never had the problem you're referring.

Comment: Well, the thing about it is that it looks as if Microsoft wants to be able to handle it the way I want (sorta). Why else would Visual Studio automatically collapse the resource into the cs file just like it does with forms and code-behinds?